# Saving webpage as MHTM file

Tags: internet-explorer, com, powershell

Given a specific URL, I'm trying to download the contents of that URL as an MHT file. I considered writing a parser/crawler, but think there must be a quicker way.

I fired up Powershell:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://www.example.com")
$ie.document.title # Just to verify the navigate worked
```

AT this point I couldn't find a way to call the menu commands, particularly SaveAs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you can see from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(VS.85).aspx there is no way to call SaveAs only navigating functions

Answer (score 2):

With VBScript

For local files

```
cscript yourscriptname.vbs file:/test.html test.mht
```

For remote files

```
cscript yourscriptname.vbs http://www.test.com/test.html test.mht
```

- 

```
Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adTypeText = 2

Set args = WScript.Arguments

if args.Count = 0 then
WScript.Echo "Usage: [CScript | WScript] mht_converter.vbs <html file> <mht filename>"
WScript.Quit 1
end if

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.CreateMHTMLBody args.Item(0)
SaveToFile objMessage, args.Item(1)

Sub SaveToFile(Msg, Fn)
Dim Strm, Dsk
Set Strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Strm.Type = adTypeText
Strm.Charset = "UTF-8"
Strm.Open
Set Dsk = Msg.DataSource
Dsk.SaveToObject Strm, "_Stream"
Strm.SaveToFile Fn, adSaveCreateOverWrite
End Sub
```

Comment: this (as of 2023) saves as a text only file

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. This still works (e.g. just tested it on https://news.ycombinator.com). Some sites break because they do user agent sniffing. And it probably fails for some "modern" sites. `US-ASCII` can be replaced with `UTF-8` if that's you mean. Also nowadays you would simply use a headless browser with Selenium or whatever. Or use a dedicated tool like https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile